# How to find the period of this sinusoid?

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I'm stuck trying to find the period of this sinusoid and would really like some pointers to different ways to approach this problem.

$$x(t) = \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5})\sin^2(\frac{8\pi t}{3})$$

I would like to turn the product into a sum and do something about that $2$ in the exponent of $\sin$

$$x(t) = \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5})\sin^2(\frac{8\pi t}{3}) = \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5})\left[ 1 - \cos(\frac{16 \pi t}{3}) \right]\frac{1}{2} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5}) + \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5}) \cos(\frac{16 \pi t}{3})\right]$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5}) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{4\pi t}{5} + \frac{16 \pi t}{3}) \cos(\frac{16 \pi t}{3} - \frac{4\pi t}{5})\right]$$

So the sum of cosines will have a period that is the LCM of of the periods of the individuals terms we added. The angular frequencies are $\frac{4\pi}{5}, \frac{92\pi}{15}, \frac{68\pi}{15}$.

Converting this to periods -> we get $\frac{5}{2}, \frac{15}{46}, \frac{15}{34}$, but the answer is $\frac{30}{4}$

Comment: To be $T$-periodic, you need $$\frac{4\pi}{5} T=2\pi n_1, \frac{92\pi }{15}T=2\pi n_2, \frac{68\pi }{15}T=2\pi n_3,$$ or $$T=\frac{5}{2}n_1=\frac{15}{46}n_2=\frac{15}{34}n_3.$$ Note that $T$ doesn't have to be an integer: You just need $n_1,n_2,n_3$ as small as possible with multiples giving a common answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the LCM, we want the smallest $T$ which is an integer multiple of the three periods. That is, we want integers $n_1,n_2,n_3$ such that $$T=\frac{5}{2}n_1=\frac{15}{46}n_2=\frac{15}{34}n_3$$ with $T$ as small as possible.

To this end we first focus on the middle equality, which rearranges to $23n_1=3n_2$. Since $23$ and $3$ are prime, this requires that $23$ divides $n_2$ and $3$ divides $n_1$. Hence there must be an integer $k$ such that $n_1=3k$ and $n_2=23k$.

With this, the third quantity of the period equality becomes redundant and we have $$T=\frac{15}{2}k=\frac{15}{34}n_3.$$

From this we deduce the value of $n_3$ and therefore know $T$ in terms of $k$. From this we deduce the smallest such value and conclude. (I leave the reader to fill in the details.)

Comment: Firstly, THANK YOU SO MUCH! 
$$$$
Secondly, how do I train my brain to think like this... $$$$How did you automatically know that the third equality was redundant? It could be that we could a $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $23n_1 = 3n_2$ but there is not $n_3$ that matched the T we found from just using $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Comment: In truth, I did mentally multiply out the last equality to get $n_3=17k$. Had it ended up as, say, $2n_3=17k$, then I'd have had to introduce another integer $\ell$ such that $n_3=17\ell$ and $k=2\ell$. But in this case that proved unnecessary and one just has $n_3=17k$ directly.

Comment: Can you explain why $2n_3 = 17k$ would cause a problem please?

Comment: $2$ and $17$ are coprime, so $17$ must divide $n_3$ and $2$ must divide $k$. Hence there must be an integer $\ell$ such that $n_3=17\ell$ and $k=2\ell$. But that means that $T=15k/2 = 15\ell$, so the period would be $T=15$ not $15/2$. (To make this more relevant, this is the analysis that would arise if the last period were $15/17$ rather than $15/34$. The issue is that $15/2$  is not longer a multiple of $15/17$, while $15$ itself is.)

Answer (score 0):

You get 7.5 if you simply apply the LCM to $\frac{4\pi t}{5} = 2\pi$ (period = 2.5) and $\frac{8\pi t}{3} = 2\pi$ (period = 0.75).